# Windows Firewall blocking applications with access granted

Tags: windows-10, firewall, windows-firewall

so, I have a problem: I need to block all outgoing connections, but allow only some programs. I got Firefox working, but some programs like Steam and Slack give problems, even if they are allowed. If I create a new rule to allow specific ip addresses, they eventually work, but it shall break again soon, due to the fact that Slack's infrastructure shift it's ip's, so their documentation states some domain wildcard to be used on firewall whitelist, but there is no such option on the windows firewall.

So I want to know: There is a way to allow a program **for sure**?

Comment: Ah, downvote without comment... How do I know why the downvote? o.0

Comment: Unfortunately there are mean users here who vote without commenting. :( Possibly your comment : "eventually it will work, but I'm sure it will break soon." is the trigger.

Comment: @LPChip edited to make that bit more clear.

Comment: @LPChip if you disagree with somebody's downvote and  with a question being -1  then I suppose you could upvote it.  However, I can see why this might deserve a downvote..You should be able to see some flaws in the question too, and thus point it out.

Comment: your title suggests that you told the firewall to block an application, not an IP, an application, and that it's not working. Yet the  body of your question is saying you told the windows firewall to block specific IPs and the program shifted IP and so the program isn't blocked, well no surprise there.. so don't make your title suggest it's something else.

Comment: i'm not that familiar with win10 but generally.. there should be a way to tell it to block incoming to an application, or outgoing from an application, or a range of IPs incoming or outgoing. win7 can i'm sure.

Comment: @barlop did you read it? My firewall is supposed to block ALL programs, except the ones I allow. I allowed slack (Since I need it for work), but it still getting blocked... It is trying to access some domains, it should be allowed, but the firewall only allow if I explicitly allow the ip currently resolving to that domain. The problem is that if slack change to another domain (say, from a.slackdata.com, to b.slackdata.com), it will be blocked, even if Slack is allowed per firewall rule!

Comment: here is a rewrite of your question- let me know what you think.. if you like it you can edit your question and replace it with this-  i'd like to allow some programs outgoing and block the rest i.e. a whitelist. The programs steam and slack change IP so I don't want to block by IP or even IP range, I'd like to block by domain but see no option to, so either that or block by application but I find that the block by application feature doesn't seem to be working with those programs   (You could also change your title to cannot block outgoing for some programs that change IP)

Comment: btw i've given you a +1 for your clarification. I don't know if the other guy will remove his downvote if you go ahead with that edit, but you may get more votes, though your question could still be improved further via troubleshooting to try to get to the bottom of why win10 is not blocking those programs when they shift IP.. whether it always fails when a program shifts IP., for example.. And anyhow, thinking about it.. what do you mean shifts IP.. If it shifts the IP that it connects out to then it should make absolutely no difference at all..it's not even a "shift".

Comment: And why would you even think to enter an individual IP.. You'd let it block all outgoing that means outgoing to Any IP.  It sounds like maybe you're filling in the wrong sections. As an experiment, try to get Firefox to Not Work.. Then at least you know you might be using the firewall correctly.